# How to avoid <<- by using assign

Tags: r

I have two pieces of code I use often in which I use the `<<-` to assign to the Global environment from within a function.  I know I should be using `assign` as it gives better control and is more predictable.  I am trying to wrap my head around using `assign` but can't transfer the `<<-` code to code that uses assign:

**A FAKE DATA SET AND THE TWO PIECES OF CODE WITH THE `<<-`**

```
#CREATE A FAKE DATA SET
df <- data.frame(
    x.2=rnorm(25),
    y.2=rnorm(25),
    g=rep(factor(LETTERS[1:5]), 5)
)
#Use split to make a list of data frames
LIST <- split(df, df$g) #split it into a list of data frames
NAMES <- names(LIST) #save the names of this for later use 
LIST <- lapply(seq_along(LIST), function(x) as.data.frame(LIST[[x]])[, 1:2])

#THE TWO PIECES OF CODE THAT USE <<-
#Use Global Assignment to Change All Variable Names of Data Frames in a List
lapply(seq_along(LIST), function(x) names(LIST[[x]]) <<-
    unlist(strsplit(names(LIST[[x]])[1:length(names(LIST[[x]]))],
    ".", fixed=T))[c(T, F)]
)
LIST

#Rename All the Data Frames in the List Using Global Assignment
lapply(seq_along(LIST), function(x) names(LIST)[[x]] <<- NAMES[x])
LIST
```

My attempts to use assign:

```
lapply(seq_along(LIST), function(x) {
    assign(names(LIST[[x]]), 
    unlist(strsplit(names(LIST[[x]])[1:length(names(LIST[[x]]))],
    ".", fixed=T))[c(T, F)],  envir=.GlobalEnv)
    }
)
LIST

lapply(seq_along(LIST), function(x) assign(names(LIST)[[x]], 
    NAMES[x], envir=.GlobalEnv))
LIST
```

Please help me to do this correctly and axplain what is wrong with my approach.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: names of objects are not a `name` in an environment so you cannot use `assign` here.

Comment: @kohske Thank you. Can you give that for the answer then and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the same thing

```
LIST <- lapply(seq_along(LIST), function(x) {
  names(LIST[[x]]) <- 
    unlist(strsplit(names(LIST[[x]])[1:length(names(LIST[[x]]))],
                    ".", fixed=T))[c(T, F)]
  LIST[[x]]
})
LIST

names(LIST) <- NAMES
LIST
```

or, to use assign

```
assign("LIST", lapply(seq_along(LIST), function(x) {
  names(LIST[[x]]) <- 
    unlist(strsplit(names(LIST[[x]])[1:length(names(LIST[[x]]))],
                    ".", fixed=T))[c(T, F)]
  LIST[[x]]
}), pos=.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: I like it in that I don't have to use `assign` or `<<-` at all.

Answer (score 3):

I do not understand why you made this task so very complicated. Isn't this just:

```
LIST <- df[, 1:2]
names(LIST) <- sapply(strsplit(names(LIST), '.', fixed = TRUE), `[`, 1)
LIST <- split(LIST, df$g)
```

i.e. you want the first 2 columns of `df`; you want the names before `.`, and you split the data frame. Reorganize your tasks and you will have a much clearer view of the problem.

BTW, `<<-` is not necessarily a horrible animal; you can use it very safely by creating the variable name in the top environment, e.g.

```
x <- 0
f <- function() x <<- 1
```

The danger only exists if you do not create the variable name at all in any places, so R has to go all the way up to the global environment, and that is usually a very bad practice.

Comment: please ignore the reproducible data.  It was just to set up the problem that arises in my tasks.  You solution only works if the data were that simple and created from a data frame and `split` which it's not.  GSee answered the problem very nicely.  +1 for the information on the global assignment.