# Why is using `<<-` frowned upon and how can I avoid it?

Tags: r

I followed the discussion over [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730651/how-to-avoid-by-using-assign) and am curious why is using`<<-` frowned upon in R. What kind of confusion will it cause?

I also would like some tips on how I can avoid `<<-`. I use the following quite often. For example:

```
### Create dummy data frame of 10 x 10 integer matrix.
### Each cell contains a number that is between 1 to 6.
df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(1:10, function(i) sample(1:6, 10, replace = TRUE)))
```

What I want to achieve is to shift every number down by 1, i.e all the 2s will become 1s, all the 3s will be come 2 etc. Therefore, all `n` would be come `n-1`. I achieve this by the following:

```
df.rescaled <- df
sapply(2:6, function(i) df.rescaled[df.rescaled == i] <<- i-1))
```

In this instance, how can I avoid `<<-`?  Ideally I would want to be able to pipe the sapply results into another variable along the lines of:

```
df.rescaled <- sapply(...)
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14166207/avoiding-global-variables-in-r/14166812#14166812

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**First point**

`<<-` is *NOT* the operator to assign to global variable. It tries to assign the variable in the nearest parent environment. So, say, this will make confusion:

```
f <- function() {
    a <- 2
    g <- function() {
        a <<- 3
    }
}
```

then,

```
> a <- 1
> f()
> a # the global `a` is not affected
[1] 1
```

**Second point**

You can do that by using `Reduce`:

```
Reduce(function(a, b) {a[a==b] <- a[a==b]-1; a}, 2:6, df)
```

or `apply`

```
apply(df, c(1, 2), function(i) if(i >= 2) {i-1} else {i})
```

**But**

simply, this is sufficient:

```
ifelse(df >= 2, df-1, df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternatives to my code. Much appreciated. Could you elaborate on the Reduce function? I am not too clear about its logic flow even after reading ?Reduce. 

I can understand that you are trying to create a function within Reduce with 2 variables. For all in `a` where it `==` to `b` minus `1`. Following that there is a `;a` and the remaining syntax of which I am lost

Comment: `Reduce` is also know as `Fold`, which is popular method in functional programming. Here is a simple explanation. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function))

Answer (score 5):

You can think of `<<-` as global assignment (approximately, because as kohske points out it assigns to the top environment unless the variable name exists in a more proximal environment).  Examples of why this is bad are here:

[Examples of the perils of globals in R and Stata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526322/examples-of-the-perils-of-globals-in-r-and-stata)

Comment: It makes more sense to think of `<<-` as an assignment that inspects the enclosing environments since `x <<- value` is equivalent to `assign('x', value, inherits=TRUE)`.  I use it for completely different purposes than `assign('x', value, pos=.GlobalEnv)`.