# Forcing a function definition to evaluate a symbol

Tags: r

Consider the example below:

```
> x=2
> myfun = function(y) x*y
> myfun(3)
[1] 6
> x=4
> myfun(3)
[1] 12
```

How would I have to define `myfun` so that its definition keeps the value of `x` such as it is at the time of definition, rather than a reference to `x`? (i.e., that the second call `myfun(3)` also yields 6 rather than 12).

EDIT: changed the title to remove incorrect terminology.

Comment: This is possible, but a little bit odd. Can you explain why you want to do this? In any case, your title is misleading (or perhaps wrong). Your function is looking up the `value` in the chain of environments. Nothing is being referenced here.

Comment: I agree with @Andrie that it's hard to conceive of a use case for this.  Perhaps what you want is a closure?

Comment: It is possible that my terminology is incorrect. What I mean by reference is that the body of the function contains "x" rather than the value held by x at the time of definition (2). I would like the body to not contain "x", i.e. to take a snapshot. Why do you think this is odd?

Comment: @AriB.Friedman Closures can definitely do this. I may modify my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @mitchus It's a little bit odd because usually if you want to take a snapshot of a variable value, you'll do that in the code.

Comment: @Andrie What if I want to pass `myfun` as an argument to another function? In another scope, `myfun` may no longer have access to `x`, or `x` may refer to something different. In any case, what would you suggest I change the title to?

Comment: Please expand on your question. Perhaps give a bit of a flavour of the problem you are trying to solve. At the moment I still don't understand what you're trying to do, so can't help. What is your use case? If you want to save the value of a variable as a snapshot, why can't you simply do that in the code?

Comment: @mitchus That's exactly the problem with using global variables.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526322/examples-of-the-perils-of-globals-in-r-and-stata and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851655/why-is-using-frowned-upon-and-how-can-i-avoid-it , and strongly consider Andrie's suggestion to pass x as a function argument, with a default value if necessary.  As an aside, you are neither passing by value nor by reference here--you're not passing at all!  So your title is not quite accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost the same question was asked on the R-help mailing list yesterday.
See the discussion on Nabble for the various ways you can do that.

http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Force-evaluation-of-a-symbol-when-a-function-is-created-td4639350.html

And here are three ways to do it (gathered from the R-help discussion):

```
x <- 2

f1 <- local({x.now <- x;function(y) x.now*y})
f2 <- evalq(function(y)a*y,env=list(a=x))

multiply_by_x <- function(x) {
    force(x)
    function(y) y*x
}

f3 <- multiply_by_x(x)
```

with results

```
> f1(3)
[1] 6
> f2(3)
[1] 6
> f3(3)
[1] 6

> x <- 4
> f1(3)
[1] 6
> f2(3)
[1] 6
> f3(3)
[1] 6
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Incidentally, in the meantime I found a fourth way which may be a bit hacky: `body(myfun) = eval(expression(parse(text = paste(x, "*y"))))`

Comment: I suggest you look at `require(fortunes); fortune(106)` before you consider the use of `parse()` again. :-)

Comment: A bit less horrible: `formals(myfun)$x=x`

Answer (score 4):

I have to guess a little bit what your purpose is. Perhaps you simply need to define one of your arguments with a default value:

```
myfun <- function(y, x=2){
  x * y
}
```

Then use it:

```
x <- 3

myfun(4)
[1] 8

myfun(x=4, 3)
[1] 12

myfun(x)
[1] 6
```

---

But perhaps you really are describing a closure.

> *An object is data with functions. A closure is a function with data.*
>
> --- John D Cook

Here is an example. First define a closure that remembers a snapshot:

```
newSnapshot <- function(x){
  xx <- x
  function(y) xx * y
}
```

Then use it:

```
x <- 10
myfun <- newSnapshot(x)

myfun(4)
[1] 40

x <- 4
myfun(5)
[1] 50
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is this:

```
myfun <- function(x = 2) {
    function(y) {
        x * y
    }
}
```

Basically we write a function that returns a function that does the computation we want. In the above `x` is set to `2` by default but you can vary this when you call `myfun`. When we call `myfun()` we save the returned function, in `foo` in the example below:

```
> foo <- myfun()
```

Now, no matter what you do to `x` in the global environment `foo()` will always use the value of `x` that was defined in the environment of `myfun()` when that function was called.

```
> foo(3)
[1] 6
> x <- 6
> foo(3)
[1] 6
> x <- 4
> foo(3)
[1] 6
```

This all works because the environment of the function created by the call to `myfun()` contains `x` and that `x` has the value of `x` that was present when the function was defined.

```
> environment(foo)$x
[1] 2
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. The thing is, at the time of writing the code I don't know the value `x` will have at the time of defining `myfun` (unlike what my poorly chosen example implies).

Answer (score 2):

Here's another closure solution:

```
myfun <- local({
  x <- 2
  list(
    f=function(y) {
      x*y
    },
    set.x=function(newx) {
      x <<- newx
    },
    get.x=function() {
      x
    }
  )
})
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
> myfun$get.x()
[1] 2
> myfun$set.x(5)
> myfun$get.x()
[1] 5
> myfun$f(3)
[1] 15
```