# How to use apply family functions instead of a for loop on a matrix?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, apply, lapply

Is there a way to use apply family functions instead of the for loop in the code below?

```
m <- matrix(0, 10, 5)
m
for (i in 2:5) m[,i] <- m[,(i-1)] + 1
m
```

Comment: not really  (although I can imagine someone will come up with something clever ...)

Comment: @BenBolker Why not?

Comment: ```invisible(lapply(2:5, function(i) m[,i] <<- m[,(i-1)] + 1)); m```

Comment: because the `apply` family is not really designed for sequential operation.

Comment: @M-- I tried too     sapply(2:7, function(i) mm[,i] <<- mm[,(i-1)] + 1)      and it works.

Comment: when looping over a vector (``2:5``), sapply and lapply are not that different.

Comment: @M-- What does <<- mean?

Comment: [What does <<- mean in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13273002)

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer:

```
> t(apply(m, 1, function(x) x = 0:4))
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    0    1    2    3    4
 [2,]    0    1    2    3    4
 [3,]    0    1    2    3    4
 [4,]    0    1    2    3    4
 [5,]    0    1    2    3    4
 [6,]    0    1    2    3    4
 [7,]    0    1    2    3    4
 [8,]    0    1    2    3    4
 [9,]    0    1    2    3    4
[10,]    0    1    2    3    4
>
```

Data used:

```
> m
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0
> for(i in 2:5) m[,i] <- m[,(i-1)] + 1
> m
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    0    1    2    3    4
 [2,]    0    1    2    3    4
 [3,]    0    1    2    3    4
 [4,]    0    1    2    3    4
 [5,]    0    1    2    3    4
 [6,]    0    1    2    3    4
 [7,]    0    1    2    3    4
 [8,]    0    1    2    3    4
 [9,]    0    1    2    3    4
[10,]    0    1    2    3    4
>
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal. I wanted to loop over the columns of the matrix.

Comment: @Joan this loops over the columns.