# Interpreting error message in if condition in R

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
a=2 

if (length(a)>1){
b<<-rowSums(c[,-(1:2)][,c(T,F)]) }

else {b<<-sum(c[seq(3,length(x),2)]) }
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: unexpected 'else' in "    else"
```

I have no idea why I am getting this message. Any ideas?

Comment: because its within a function

Comment: This part of the code is within a function and I want to write to a variable outside the function that's why I'm using <<, but if I change to = the error still remains (i am only pasting this part of the code)

Comment: I was going to edit the code formatting to clean it up, but then I looked at the error message and realized that the immediate error is actually coming from the formatting of the code itself.

Comment: In particular, from `?Control`: "In particular, you should not have a newline between } and else to avoid a syntax error in entering a if ... else construct at the keyboard or via source." But given the use of the hated `<<-` I suspect there are other things going awry here as well.

Comment: Jilber the things you propose are not related to the error message. These variables are all nicely defined in my program and do not give an error if I enter them separately

Comment: what is the problem with <<-?

Comment: Using `<<-` is considered (very) bad practice in general, and is often a sign that you need to rethink the way you've structured your code. Making assignments that stretch across environments like that can get very dangerous and cause problems that are nearly impossible to debug. People use it, but only very sparingly, and only when there is literally no other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the R definition:

> When the if statement is not in a block the else, if present, must
>   appear on the same line as the end of statement2. Otherwise the new
>   line at the end of statement2 completes the if and yields a
>   syntactically complete statement that is evaluated. A simple solution
>   is to use a compound statement wrapped in braces, putting the else on
>   the same line as the closing brace that marks the end of the
>   statement.

([R Language Definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html))

So, the 'else' must me in the same line as '}'. Either

```
a=2 

if (length(a)>1){
b<<-rowSums(c[,-(1:2)][,c(T,F)]) } else {b<<-sum(c[seq(3,length(x),2)]) }
```

or

```
a=2 

if (length(a)>1){
b<<-rowSums(c[,-(1:2)][,c(T,F)]) 
} else {b<<-sum(c[seq(3,length(x),2)]) }
```

but is still a bad code/identation pattern. I'd try something like

```
a=2 

if (length(a)>1) {
    b<<-rowSums(c[,-(1:2)][,c(T,F)]) 
} else {
    b<<-sum(c[seq(3,length(x),2)]) 
}
```

to avoid further mistakes, or the suggested 'ifelse' function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for

```
ifelse(expr, if-case, else-case)
```

Actually it seems that your if is being executed and then you try to write an 'else' (but without if). Are you doing this code in a shell or is it written in a text file?

EDIT (explanation):

```
x <- 1
b <- ifelse(x == 1, 1,2)
cat(b,"\n")
[1] 1
```

So if x == 1, then b gets 1, otherwise it gets 2. You can exchange '1' and '2' with functions or anything you want.

Comment: can you explain this please?

Comment: First of all: Arun is correct when saying that your "<<" is wrong. An assigment is done with : "<-"

Comment: You mean an explanation for 'ifelse'?

Comment: <<- is used if you want to write to a variable outside a function, I have this command within a function and am assigning to a variable outside a function. changint to <- doens't solve the problem

Comment: for example: ifelse(b>1, b<-rowSums(c[,-(1:2)][,c(T,F)]), c<-rowSums(c[,-(1:2)][,c(T,F)])) ?

Comment: Yes, I think that will work

Answer (score 1):

To solve your immediate problem, as @joran pointed out in the comments, you just need to have the `}` ending your `if` statement on the same line as the `else`.

```
a <- FALSE

if (a) {
    print("a is true")
} else {  ## Works
    print("a is false")
}

if (a) {
    print("a is true")
} ## Doesn't work
else {
    print("a is false")
}
```

When a line ends and a statement *could* have ended, R stops expecting more input related to that statement.
This is the same reason that

```
1 +
2
```

gives 3, but

```
1
+ 2
```

won't.

I'd also strongly recommend that you rethink the `<<-`. It's much better form in R to have your functions return things than have them just change things. See also: [Why is using `<<-` frowned upon and how can I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9851655/903061)