# Assignment operators in R: '<-' and '<<-'

Tags: r, variable-assignment

What are the differences in the assignment operators `<-` and `<<-` in R?

And when should `<<-` be used?

Comment: this was asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5785290/what-is-the-difference-between-assign-and-in-r

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9851655/324364) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904124/global-and-local-variables-in-r). The latter in particular is a very close duplicate.

Comment: I'd simply forget about `<<-`, I've never seen a valid use for it. Global variables are not needed, and for ugly, hard to read and maintain code.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra, you don't consider closures a valid use?  I'm thinking particularly of the case where `<<-` doesn't assign to the global environment, but rather, to an intermediate enclosing environment.

Comment: @BrodieG Saying there is *no* place for `<<-` is probably not true (although I have not used `<<-` in my several years of R programming). But in the vast majority of situations it is not necessary. In addition, the cases where it is applicable are probably quite complex situations (you mention nested environments), while `<<-` is more abused by novice programmers in simple situations.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra, yes you are right.

Comment: @BrodieG you mentioned in the vast majority of situations `<<-` is not necessary. What would you have done instead in my proposed answer (found below) for the usage of `<<-`?

Comment: @csiu, see **[this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659133/local-variables-within-aes/10659410#10659410)** in another SO question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<-` assigns an object to the environment in which it is evaluated (local scope).  `<<-` assigns an object to the next highest environment that the name is found in or the global namespace if no name is found.  See the documentation [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/assignOps.html).

`<<-` is usually only used in functions, but be careful.  `<<-` can be much harder to debug because it is harder to trace the evaluation of the assignment.  It is better to write functions with `return` statements instead.

Hadley Wickham has a good explination in his [Advanced R Programming Book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html#binding).