# R operator: <<-

Tags: r, operators

What's the difference between "<-" and "<<-" in R? I have read the help file in R. But I still don't understand their difference. Could any one provide an example? Thanks a lot!

Comment: From [@kohske's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851655/why-is-using-frowned-upon-and-how-can-i-avoid-it/9851794#9851794): "<<- is NOT the operator to assign to global variable. It tries to assign the variable in the nearest parent environment"

Comment: This is not the exact duplicate of @beginneR link, but this should be marked as one so the provided link will educate newbies how to properly use this operator

Answer (score 0):

used inside a function, the standard "<-" operator defines a variable inside this function and the variable will not be available outside.

Using "<<-" enables your function to define a variable outside, aka in the global environment, for further use.

That is quite useful in fact!

Comment: Wrong. This should be never used to assign to the global environment. The only good use for it is via lexical scope

Comment: @DavidArenburg I get it. When I use "<<-", R won't create a new variable but to look for the variable in parent environment. Am I right?

Comment: It will first look in the parent environment and upwards, in case it won't find any, it will create a new one the global environment